# How to make spirals into endcaps for strokes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, path-effects

I'm creating an illustration for a quote and I want to finish the strokes with swirls -like in the image below- but I'm having problems making them look similar. I'm using a spiral tool and adding a circle dot to the stroke but the results differs from one to another.

Do you know a method to make them and then to replicate so they mantain a visual unity or can you point out a tutorial for a similar process (perfect swirls at the end of a stroke path)?

[image: see the cyan circle]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on your edit if I understand correctly you want to find a way to have a spiral on the end of paths? If that's not correct please comment or make another [edit] to further clarify. If that is the case, I'm not sure it can be done beyond making a custom arrow which is a very complicated task.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I want to have a similar spiral at the end of each path so they look alike one to eachother. I'll check for the custom arrow proccess. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

One good trick is to use the same spiral/shape over and over again. Then mirror, rotate and cut it about. You want the same after all, then use the same.

[image]

**Image 1**: Spirals for the same stock. The magenta one is rotated and mirrored segment of the blue one.

In practice make one bigger master spiral and replicate that. Since the spiral is also invariant in every place it should work out nicely.

[image: Anim]

**Image 2**: Animation showing what segment the object was originally rotated and reflected from.

*Please note*: The spirals in the demo image are not spirals they are alternating half circles of progressing size.

[image]

**Image 3**: Those ends in the postage stamp are not spirals but consist of strings of half circles. Comparison of a spiral and half circled spiral fitted to that spirals characteristics.