# Merge circle with lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's say, I am trying to recreate a shape (the circle attached within the M shape) like the attached image. Is there any way to do this simply and perfect?

They way I have tried it is not giving me the desired result.

- Covert anchor point of the circle,
- Drag until it's almost in line with the to other ends...
- Fail.

Thanks in advance!

Image:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, there was recently a similar question please read **[This](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71816/how-are-these-swirly-line-frames-made/71820#71820)** and see if that helps you.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for the warm welcome, and that thread certainly helped to me to get a better view of how to solve similar problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A detailed explination of of creating more complex shapes can be found [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/71820/52050). In this specific case though you can easily start with a circle and extend the paths with the pen tool.

### Start with a circle:

[image: Start with a circle]

### Rotate 45 degrees and delete the top section:

[image: Rotate and delete one section]

### Using the Pen Tool, extend the path from each open anchor point:

[image: Extend the paths]

From there it's easy enough to complete the image using the pen tool.

### Finished image:

[image: Finished image]

Tip: Use a grid when working with shapes like this and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to constrain your angles when working with drawing tools.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Pen tool to create the "M" shape, then select the anchor points like in the screenshot I attached and increase the corner radius to the maximum.
[image: select these three anchor points]

[image: increase the corner radius]

[image: increase the stroke weight]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the most accurate way to accomplish this is to create the M and circle shapes separately, getting them as close to the same line weight as possible, then converting both to outlines/outlining strokes.

Center the circle shape with the M shape using the Align tool, and position the circle vertically to where you'd like it to be.

Once both shapes are in place and overlapping, open the Pathfinder window > click Divide. This will allow you to delete any unwanted pieces and be left with only the ones you want. Then you can always go back to Cai's suggestion for extending anchor points from there.

Once you're done with the shapes, you should do Pathfinder window > Merge.

Comment: Mitchell asked the question. I believe it was my suggestion you're talking about ;)

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry!