# How can I recreate this using the vector tool in sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

[image: vector]

How can I achieve the same look? I’m unable to get the curves perfect.

Comment: You may achive better results if you do not think of vector graphics as drawn, but rather constructed. Although sketch is a bit painful as a general vector illustration tool, and i dont have a mac at home to convert my older answer to be sketch specific. You may still find [this explanation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71816/how-are-these-swirly-line-frames-made/71820#71820) enlightening. In short dont try to think the wing as one shape but 3 separate ones. Those separate ones again consist of two thinhs namely  a line and a circle segment.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create a blocky wing shape using the Vector tool and then select the vector points and set the Corners property to make them rounded.

You could also build the shape using multiple rectangles in a union and use the same technique for rounding the corners.

[image: Wing shape with rounded vector points]

**Edit**:

To also get correct lines I would use a slightly different technique where each wing segment is constructed separately.

[image: Wing technique 2]

Comment: Thank you! Question. How can I add the lines to that path? (The lines inside the wing?)