# How can I make this shape in illustrator? (without pen tool if possible)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

[image: How can I make this shape easily in illustrator?strong text]

I cannot seem to get this shape with two perfect half circles with the pen tool. How hard is it? I try to avoid using it if possible so unfortunately I am not really proficient at using it. Is there another way of getting this shape? I imported this shape so I can see the anchor points but still I cannot come close to replicating it because of how clumsy the pen tool controls are.

Comment: Your not actually supposed to freedand with the pen tool you know.

Comment: The Pen Tool (aka Bézier tool) in Illustrator isn't clumsy, in fact it works almost exactly the same as most other vector image editing application. I agree it's certainly unintuitive for beginners, but that's only because it's a complex tool that requires some practice/familiarity. Try the [Bézier Game](https://bezier.method.ac/). It's a fun way to learn how to use the Pen Tool.

Comment: @BillyKerr maybe op is used to b-splines. In anycase i think there is a prerequisit to drawing with pen tool that is often skipped. And that is how do you draw accurately on a computer software like illustrator, inkscape etc. So one needs to review how to snap, and how to make numeric input ([like](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/how-to-create-a-vector-curve-programmatically/38010#38010), [or like](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71816/how-are-these-swirly-line-frames-made/71820?r=SearchResults#71820),but realistically about 20% of my answers revolve a

Answer (score 14):

Do this:

1. Draw a circle
2. Use Scissors Tool and cut it into an arc (Remove the side you don't use)
3. Apply a thick stroke with a rounded cap
4. Expand.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Draw a straight line, apply a thick stroke, and round end caps.
2. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to select the Anchor Point Tool [image], mouse over the middle of the path, and click and drag to bend it.
3. *Object > Expand*

[image]

Another possibility is to use the Curvature Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to make the initial curve. Three simple clicks is all it takes.

[image]

Comment: I'm jealous of this :P

Comment: @Vikas LOL. It would be even easier to make the initial curved path with the Pen tool (using one tool instead of two), but the OP doesn't want to use it. Such a shame.

Comment: this is what OP wanted. This is one nice trick since OP needed "without pen tool". And it's faster.

Comment: @Vikas actually that got me to think about the Curvature Tool, so I've added that too in the answer, for a single tool alternative.

Comment: lol I also just tried the same, but I felt it is just another brother of pen tool  but it's not a pen tool theorectically

Comment: @Vikas - It's like the Pen Tool, but for people who can only drive an automatic car ;)

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer is a quick and efficient way to do this. Another possible way is by using `Object > Envelop Distort > Make with warp`

1. Draw a horizontal path with stroke and make it rounded corners in *Stroke Panel* (for any other angle, you'd need different warp values. I'm using horizontal path)
2. Apply the Envelop Distort warp (apply the amount you need)
3. Expand it. You'll get curved path. You can still control the stroke width. Further expanding it will give you the shape.
   [image]